# whois command not found?

Tags: kali-linux

Using kali linux 2016.01

```
pip install whois
Requirement already satisfied

apt-get update
apt-get install whois
Package 'whois' has no installation candidate
```

typing `whois google.com` on terminal says command not found. Any solution?

Comment: "apt-cache search whois" doesn't return anything?

Comment: Don't shout at us! (Writing in all caps ~ shouting)

Comment: 'apt-cache search whois' gives some info about other packages. is the command whois removed in kali linux 2016.01?

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed Kali Linux 2016.1 and did an update.
The whois command works fine.

```
root@Kali:~# cat /etc/issue
Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l

root@Kali:~# dpkg -l whois

 ||/ Name                  Version         Architecture    Description
 +++-=====================-===============-===============-================================================
 ii  whois                 5.2.12          amd64           intelligent WHOIS client

 root@Kali:~# whois www.google.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

Server Name: WWW.GOOGLE.COM.AR
Registrar: ENOM, INC.
Whois Server: whois.enom.com
Referral URL: http://www.enom.com
```

You can try to install manually:

```
root@Kali:~# apt  install  whois
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
whois is already the newest version (5.2.12).


root@Kali:~# apt-cache policy whois
whois:
  Installed: 5.2.12
  Candidate: 5.2.12
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.12 500
    500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy whois` show?

Comment: added that command to my answer above